# django admin automatic rtl for some languages

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to add multi language support for a django project using Django i18n official documentaion:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/

When I change the LANGUAGE_CODE to something like 'fa', by default the admin panel changes to RTL.
But the problem is when I use other RTL languages like 'ku' (kurdish) the page remains in ltr.
I know we can change the css manualy, but wonder what is the problem here and how some languages like Arabic or persian does the RTL part automaticaly but others dont.

Thanks in advance

```
# settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ku', _('Kurdish')),
    ('fa', _('Persian')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    Path(BASE_DIR, 'django_i18n', 'locale'),
]

# url.py
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
) +static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

just found the answer here:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/global_settings.py#L158

So all I had to do was add this to setting.py:

```
LANGUAGES_BIDI = ["ku",]
```